# Frequent contacts disappeared

Tags: contacts, phone-app, call-history

I have a Moto G5 with Android 7.0 and Phone 3.00.00.

It used to be the case that when I called one of my contacts, they would appear in the "Speed dial" tab of the phone app, just after my favorite contacts.  For some reason, my phone app's speed dial tab doesn't show any frequent contacts any more.  Only favorite contacts appear.  The call history tab still shows these calls, so I am using that for now.

Do NOT ask me to look for a "Show frequently contacted" setting.  I have checked both the phone app's settings and the contact app's settings and I don't see a setting for "Show frequently contacted" which seems to be a Samsung setting.

Comment: samsung setting? moto is stock android and samsung is custom ui. please reply with your current phone app version in moto. speed dial shows starred contacts first, scroll down to view dialled numbers in speed dial.

Comment: @RahulGopi thanks for your comment.  I have edited the question with the phone app version, as well as the reason for mentioning the samsung setting.  Speed dial ONLY shows starred/favorite contacts (as I said), and I only have two, so there's not enough contacts to scroll.